# Is it possible to deploy an Azure DevOps agent into Azure while have the server on-premises behind VPN?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

In other words, an on-premise Azure DevOps server would be able to send requests to the agent, but the agent would not be able to send those to server, because the latter is not exposed to the outside world.

Answer (score 0):

I think, no. How do you plan to register that agent if it can not send requests to your Azure DevOps server?

Comment: The agent, of course, must be manually registered with the server. Once the server knows its address it can interrogate it.

Comment: @mark However, server does not send requests to the build agent that is not online. So now, the question is: who is trying to detect online build agents. 1) Server sends request to each build agent 2) or build agent periodically says "Im started and Im here". I think, the second option is more real (but not sure :) ).

Comment: @mark I've checked that. I've disabled 8080 port on my build agent firewall. Server showed my build agent is offline on the next build.

Comment: Yes, I know it does not work out of the box. But maybe there is configuration for that. This is a very real hybrid cloud scenario, like my organisation has on-prem TFS behind VPN, but we want to integrate better with Azure without having to move all of our source code to there, not right away at least.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by using Deployment groups.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=58UfRxxAWhE

Comment: The youtube shows the agent is running behind the firewall on prem, but the Azure DevOps Services run in Azure. The agent has no problem talking to the server. My scenario is reverse - the server is on prem and the agent should be in Azure. Agent CANNOT talk to the server, but the server can talk to the agent. I think I described it clearly in the question.

Comment: Can you elaborate in your answer?

Comment: Maybe this can help:

https://devopsnet.com/2014/06/11/connecting-your-azure-environment-to-your-office-vpn/